# Tablespace e arquivos de dados no Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Um *tablespace* é um arquivo de dados que armazena várias tabelas, como um arquivo zip? Qual a relação entre *tablespace* e arquivo de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablespace é um local para armazenar arquivos de dados. O arquivo de dados costuma ter várias tabelas, mas nada impede que tenha uma só ou mesmo uma parte de uma tabela. Índices também.

Geralmente cada Tablespace está em uma unidade de armazenamento diferente e é uma organização lógica, justamente para poder diferenciar onde os arquivos estarão. É só um facilitador para indicar onde os dados estão fisicamente.

Se conhece *namespace* de linguagens de programação, é basicamente isto, é só uma forma de dar nome para um conjunto de coisas menores.

[image: Tablespace Oracle]

[Retirado da documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Tablespace corresponde a uma área lógica onde o oracle armazena a coleção de arquivos que compõem se banco de dados, datafiles são os arquivos físicos propriamente dito.