# O que é uma página em um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados

Por que os sistemas gerenciadores de bancos de dados usam páginas (*pages*) para organizar os dados? Qual é a vantagem de fazer assim? Todos os sistemas trabalham dessa forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem dois motivos principais:

- as estruturas de dados que eles são montados costumam funcionar com páginas de dados
- em geral isso é mapeado diretamente ao armazenamento de massa

Em grande parte dos bancos de dados, praticamente de qualquer modelo de organização, incluindo relacional, documento, grafo, etc., é usado uma forma de árvore ([exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/576712/101)), seja LSM, seja B ([já falei mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101)), ou alguma outra, e precisam de páginas para organizar mais facilmente os dados e ir mudando de lugar quando necessário (algo muito importante em dados voláteis) de forma mais simples.

Aí junta a fome com a vontade de comer, porque o sistema de arquivos de praticamente qualquer sistema operacional usa um sistema parecido, afinal ele não deixa de ser um banco de dados, então as páginas da árvore podem casar com as páginas do *file system*, o que facilita ainda mais.

Lembrando que geralmente você não pode escrever nada menor que uma página inteira em armazenamento de massa (HDD, SSD, e até NVRAM, onde eu já vi, pode ter algum diferente). Em alguns casos a página do banco de dados contém algumas páginas do FS. É possível ter páginas do DB menores que do SO, mas não costuma dar bom resultado em qualquer circunstância.

Em geral a própria memória virtual que é mapeada para o sistema de arquivos também trabalha com páginas da mesma forma, o que facilita o cache.

Uma página pode ter vários objetos de dados (linhas, por exemplo), ou pode até precisar de várias páginas para guardar um objeto grande. A forma como cada banco de dados administra isso varia bastante. Tem SGDBs que só permitem que o objeto tenha o tamanho máximo de uma página, mas permitem alguma indireção para alguns tipos de dados que fiquem fora do objeto normal, fazendo uma espécie de normalização implícita (geralmente chama-se *overflow page*).

O tamanho mais comum de páginas é 4KB, mas alguns sistemas optam por algo entre 8KB e 32KB, em raros casos 64KB, ou podem ser configurados com 2KB ou menos.

A tamanho ideal pode variar de acordo com a maneira como os dados são acessados e escritos no padrão que está sendo usado. Alguns sistemas permitem mudar isso por base de dados ou até por [*tablespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/228497/101).

Em alguns sistemas o travamento para acesso concorrente só pode ser feito no nível da página.

Claro que a página pode conter metadados que custaria caro fazer para todos os registros de dados individuais, e eles podem ser bem úteis. Inclusive podem ter algum [*checksum*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/580167/101), que nem faz sentido ter menor que uma página do arquivo físico.

[Exemplo do PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html). E [do SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html).

Obviamente que podem existir exceções, mas é bem raro, se não for algo experimental, precisa de uma motivação muito forte para não fazer assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).